# How to validate saml [response] using Public key provided by IDP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I got SAML response from my Idp server with public key certificate.

I want to integrate this with my Spring Boot app [service provider], 
 so my question is :-

1.How is the SignatureValue filed (in the saml token ) and Public key provided to us can be used to get the identity of the token.

2.How can this be integrated with my Spring Boot app , In which I have used spring Security library.

Please help.

Comment: (1) is taken care of by spring-security-saml if configured properly with metadata of the IdP and (2) go through this [example](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample)

Comment: where and how can i use public key to validate saml response in this example ?

Comment: the example imports metadata of the service provider via a URL; the metadata contains the public key. Validation is done by spring-security-saml based on the metadata.

Comment: Validation happens in `OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider` (spring boot 2.3.5.RELEASE)